# Generated wsdl missing types definition weblogic 12c

Tags: java, xsd, wsdl, weblogic, jax-ws

When I deploy a web service to weblogic 12c, some types are missing in the generated wsdl (I check the XSDs in the imports).

I didn't have this issue on weblogic 11, is this linked to differences in jax-ws implementation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a workaround :

You can configure JAXB providers at application-Level instead of depending on your application server.

Check Oracle documentation below :

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24964/data_types.htm#WSGET347